# I want to scape the table "use of proceeds" off this text file. Is there a way for me to do it in python?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

[The table I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kqKe.png)I am new to the python web scraping. I am trying to scrape the table off a text file[text_file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/745732/000120677414002818/0001206774-14-002818.txt). The text file is attached, and I want to scrape the table of "use of proceeds" into an excel file or at least a text file.

I started with a little bit of the code but have no idea how to proceed from there.

```
url_text = requests.get(text_file)
data = url_text.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find('td')
tables1 = tables.find_all('td')
```

But the return of tables1 is none.
Can someone help me with this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is a single line mistake which you are committing at this line.

```
>>> tables = soup.find('td')
```

This line will find only the first occurrence of the tag td in the html page that you have requested.
And hence, when you use this result in the next line, it will not find any other tag called 'td'.
You need to simply change this line to the line given below.

```
>>> tables = soup.findAll('td')
```

This would do the job for you! Now you have all the table tags as shown in the text file. Then, you just need to iterate over tables, and get the text out of it.

```
>>> for data in tables:
     print(data.text) # Anything you want to do.
```

Comment: It seems like the table title is separated from the table. How can I find the table title first, then find the closest table?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    df = pd.read_html(
        url, attrs={'style': 'LINE-HEIGHT: 14pt; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse'})[0]
    print(df)
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/745732/000120677414002818/0001206774-14-002818.txt")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/71b91a4d18440d6d1085b6461701a629/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: hello thanks for your comments, but the code I run returns error: 'html5lib not found, please install it'. The error still shows after I installed the html5lib

Comment: Another question, I am trying to scrape the table "use of proceed", but after I add the match = 'USE OF PROCEED', it returns no tables found. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: @FanqiGraceMeng well let's move step by step then. have you installed `pip install html5lib` ? and if yes, are you using `virtual environment` to make sure that you installed the module within it? And for the specific table, could you edit your question and show the desired table?

Comment: @ αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη, the code works fine after I restarted my PyCharm. The table I am looking for is titled "CAPITALIZATION" under the USE OF PROCEEDS, with several comments and the actual table. I attached the table I want in the question. Can you please help me with the table scrap, thanks in advance.